# How to call a function inside a WPF form outside of it

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the function inside of the window i am trying to access

```
public void LogConsole(string message, string type = "Default")
{
    Thread LogConsoleThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ConsoleLogBox.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {message}";
        }));

    });
    LogConsoleThread.Start();

    ConsoleLogBox.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

this is the function that is outside of the mainwindow trying to acess it

```
public static void LogConsole(string message, string type = "Default")
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).LogConsole(message, type);
    }));
}
```

This code was working before i added another form which i made a startup form. So when the MainWindow form is no longer the start up form i get an error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" which im assuming is because it is now trying to acess the start up form although this code is only ever ran when the MainWindow form is the only one open so i am not surre what to do to edit it.

I know that i can use MVVM although for this project i can not use MVVM as it is too late. So I **cannot** use MVVM.

Comment: Check if the mainwindow exists and is loaded before calling a method on it: `if ((bool)Application.Current.MainWindow?.IsLoaded) { /* dispatcher invoke etc. */ }`

Comment: I get the same error when I try that.

Comment: `if ((Application.Current.MainWindow?.IsLoaded).GetValueOrDefault())`

Comment: When i try it out now nothing is outputted and the only form open is the MainWindow form. i should also note that the name of the form is MainWindow but it is not the start up form

Comment: You’re only calling it before the main window is created. Create the window earlier, or call the method later. You give no hint as to what your goals are here so I can’t do more than tell you how to avoid the null reference exception.

Comment: You can’t call a method through a null reference. You just can’t. If your only goal is to add a line of text to a text box, I suggest doing so after that text box has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainWindow` class, add the following:

```
public static MainWindow Instance;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
}
```

Change your `static` "outside" method to:

```
public static void LogConsole(string message, string type = "Default")
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {

        if (MainWindow.Instance != null)
        {
            (MainWindow.Instance.LogConsole(message, type)
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something if MainWindow isn't loaded yet
        }
    }));
}
```

And change your "inside" method to:

```
public void LogConsole(string message, string type = "Default")
{            
    ConsoleLogBox.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {message}";
    ConsoleLogBox.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

Notice I've removed the creation of a new thread, because all you were doing was creating a new thread to immediately call the UI thread again, which is pointless.
For the `static` version, unless you plan on calling it from another thread, you can remove `Dispatcher.Invoke`. I left it in just in case.